# How do I get the name of a network printer?

Tags: linux, printing, cups

If I have the IP address of a network printer, how can I get its name using the command line? With the GUI tool `system-config-printer` the printer's name and IP address shows up in the list.

Comment: Have you tried `lpinfo -v -h ${ip_addres}:631`?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Thanks for the input but this gives me the same output as `lpinfo -v`; the socket URI with the IP address is displayed but not the name of the printer.

Comment: ping -a should work, among other things.

Comment: @Debra `ping -a` gives me the same output as without the `-a`, i.e. no hostname.

Comment: Good to know, though odd -- "ping -a xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" is supposed to resolve the address to the hostname, and I often use it that way. Perhaps because it's http?

Answer (score 1):

nmap surely accomplishes the tas, see the line *http-title*

```
$ nmap -A -T5 192.168.73.10

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-19 23:58 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.73.10
Host is up (0.068s latency).
Not shown: 875 closed ports, 122 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE    VERSION
7/tcp    open  echo
80/tcp   open  http       HP Color LaserJet 2600n http config 4.0.2.38
|_http-title: HP Color LaserJet 2600n
9100/tcp open  jetdirect?
Service Info: Device: printer

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 161.86 seconds
```

Comment: When I run the nmap command it never seems to complete. The only output I get is `Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-20 16:52 CEST`

Comment: You have a connectivity problem in your LAN, not a problem with your printer.

Comment: How come the GUI tool `system-config-printer` can get the name of the printer then?

Comment: Very likely that you didn't wait long enough for the nmap command to complete. The following command took nearly ten minutes at my office network:  

nmap -A -T5 175.30.4.1/24 2>&1 | tee nmapscan.out